# Vue.js and Observer Pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, vue.js, observer-pattern

Is data binding or event handling of Vue.js associated with Observer pattern of Design Pattern?

I listened from my co-worker.
He said Frontend-framework's data binding or event handling is associated with Observer Pattern.
He also said 'If you wanna know about two-ways-binding, I think you should research observer-pattern'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Vue's Reactivity system is definitely an example of the Observer Pattern:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: Yes! Specifically the part about a _watcher_ AKA _Observer_ being assigned to each _data_ _property._